# ios constraint removing gesture

Tags: ios, swift

This is a little hard to describe so let me know if more info is needed. VIEW 1 only appears on specific criteria. This view appears before the other views. I have an outlet constraint set on VIEW 2 for the top position to change if VIEW 1 appears.

If VIEW1 appears, set VIEW 2 top constraint to 143 else it is 0

```
@IBOutlet weak var view2Top: NSLayoutConstraint!

//set in function where criteria is checked
view2Top.constant = 143
```

This works until the criteria is meet. But when VIEW1 appears it causes the tap gesture set on VIEW 3, bordered red, to stop working. Hide VIEW 1 and the tap gesture works.  Now VIEW 4 tap works fine and it and VIEW 3 are done the same. VIEW 3 has a view, red border, sitting over the top of the map that the outlet is connected to.

[image]

VIEW 3 is set like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapViewOverlay: UIView!
let mapTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

In the viewDidLoad the gesture is defined as such

```
mapTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.mapTapped))
mapViewOverlay.addGestureRecognizer(mapTap)
```

mapTapped just does

```
func mapTapped(){
    print("mapTapped")}
```

I've tried setting the outlet to be strong but didn't matter. Anyone have an idea of what needs to be changed so the gesture isn't lost?

Update.

So the solution was to remove the overlay over the map, bordered red, disable any interaction with the map and set VIEW3 to have the tap gesture. This actually simplified the layout. Actual cause is still unknown but maybe the overthinking it was actually the cause.

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Changing auto layout doesn't affect its gestures. Is view3 still in super view's bounds when view1 is appeared?

Comment: @Ryan when I look at the debug hierarchy it appears so. Is there a better way to ensure it is?

Comment: The simplest way must be to set `clipsToBounds = true` to its superview. If you can still see the view3, it is in the bounds.

Comment: Woo. It disappeared. That looks to be the prob. Any suggestions on an area to look to resolve this?

Comment: Take that back. I had removed the border so it was gone. Adding border back and it is still there.

Comment: Maybe you are not using autolayout modifies the size of superview. If I were you, I will use UITableView to show those content. But if you don't want for some reason, you better set constraits to set correct super view's size.